# I do not understand why my file path is incorrectly formatted for os.makedir

Tags: python, windows, operating-system, os.path

I am trying to teach myself Python on a Windows 10 laptop. I have just reached the chapter on the os library. I have written the code for a simple program that creates a backup folder.
However when I run the program I receive the error:

*OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\Users\\Gareth Preston\\Documents\\Celtx\\Backup Wed Jun 24 14:22:55 2020'*

So I can see that I am trying to use an invalid path with os.makedirs but I do not understand why the path is invalid. I've been looking at stackoverflow answers and I think I am using os.path.join correctly but something must be missing. Here is my code:

```
import os, shutil, time

root_src_dir = os.path.join('C:\\','Users','Gareth Preston','Documents','Celtx')
backup_folder_name = 'Backup ' + time.asctime()
root_dst_dir = os.path.join('C:\\','Users','Gareth Preston','Documents','Celtx',backup_folder_name)
   
for src_dir, dirs, files in os.walk(root_src_dir):
    dst_dir = src_dir.replace(root_src_dir, root_dst_dir, 1)
    if not os.path.exists(dst_dir):
        os.makedirs(dst_dir)

    for file_ in files:
        src_file = os.path.join(src_dir, file_)
        dst_file = os.path.join(dst_dir, file_)
        if os.path.exists(dst_file):
            os.remove(dst_file)
        shutil.copy(src_file, dst_dir)

print(">>>>>>Backup Complete<<<<<<")
```

Please could someone tell me what I am misunderstanding?

Comment: try adding a double-quote around the root_dst_string with ``os.path.join(`'\"',..., '\"')```.   The spaces are likely causing the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer. It worked and I never would have thought of it myself.

Comment: @Fubar, spaces are not an issue for file API calls. The problem is the colon in the name. Microsoft filesystems reserve colon for [file streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-streams). Some filesystems in Windows actually allow colon in filenames (e.g. a VirtualBox shared folder). But unless one has a very good reason to go against the grain, with a filesystem that's known to support colon in filenames, it's best to handle it as always reserved.